# mongoose - how to wait for saving

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a findOne query after I get the result I want to save some data.
my findOne query searches in same data that was saved.

my problem is that the findOne accurse before the save was complete.

I want to prevent a duplicate dataRow.

```
return models.LogDashboard.findOne({'user.email': user.email, title: conditions[condition].title})
        .then((oldLog) => {
            if (oldLog) {
                return Promise.resolve('log already was created');
            } else {
                    let log = {
                        'user': {
                            'first' : user.name.first,
                            'last'  : user.name.last,
                            'phone' : user.phone.country + user.phone.number,
                            'email' : user.email,
                            'type'  : user.type,
                            'status': user.status
                        },
                        'done' : false,
                        'date' : new Date(),
                        'title': conditions[condition].title,
                        'todo' : conditions[condition].todo
                    };
                    newLog = new models.LogDashboard(log);

                    return newLog.save()
                        .then((log) => {
                            return Promise.resolve('Log was Created');
                        })
                        .catch((e) => {
                            return Promise.reject('Error' + e);
                        });
            }
        }).catch((e) => {
            return Promise.reject('Error' + e);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Short solution and probably not best one, but have you tried using timeout function?

```
setTimeout(function(){

return newLog.save()
                    .then((log) => {
                        return Promise.resolve('Log was Created');
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        return Promise.reject('Error' + e);
                    });

}, 500);
```

Don't know what is function used for, but this should solve issue.

Comment: I have this as a final solution If I will not find any other solution.

Comment: Best possible solution would be promises, and after this happens to use then save for newLog.